# Can't declare function with a name 'lang' in Polymer 2.0

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I have been using Polymer 1.0 for about 2 years, so it's time to upgrade to 2.0. But, I have found propably reserved function that can't be declared. ( I am using now 2.3.1 version)

I tried to create a function with a simple name `lang`. This function works in all of my projects as an internationalization function ( in Polymer 1.x ). So I would like to continue with using it. Unfortunately the name `lang` is ignored by Polymer. Whenever I call `this.lang()` or in binding `[[lang()]]` I get `undefined`

You can reproduce it with Polymer starter kit. Install it, and wherever in the project declare a function named `lang` and call it.

I found out that this has something to do with extending `Polymer.element` because when I extended `HTMLElement`, it worked. Is there something I am missing? I tried to search in documentation but I didn't find anything. Even on the internet no one is complaining even this name could be (propably) oftenly used

Is there a way to solve this? or do I have to just use different name of function? Are there other reserved names for functions?

Some example:

```
class MyGuidepost extends Polymer.Element {
        static get is() {
            return 'my-guidepost';
        }

        static get properties() {
            return {
                prop1: {
                    type: String,
                    value: 'my-guidepost'
                }
            };
        }

        ready() {
            super.ready();
            this.test();
        }

        lang(param) {
            return "asdsad";
        }

        test() {
            console.warn(this.lang()); // calling lang function returns undefined
        }
    }

    window.customElements.define(MyGuidepost.is, MyGuidepost);
}
```

Comment: I tested the same and its working good when used `_lang` but not with `lang`

Comment: related: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/2619

Comment: @ThomasOrlita thank you, I was trying to find something like this a long time..